# How can I get ASP.NET MVC model binding to bind to just an underscore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am using a JS library that passes one of its query string parameters as just an underscore, ex.

```
 SomeUrl/?_ABC123
```

I tried creating a simple class with an underscore as a property but that doesn't seem to work (nothing appears to be bound).

```
public class SomeUrlModel
{
   public string _ { get; set; }
}
```

Am I stuck with just creating a custom model binder?

(I could easily just grab this out of the query string but it'd be nice to not have to embed this kind of code everyplace where I can expect this querystring).

**Update**

Well, apparently my test was incorrect. An underscore **IS** being properly bound. Something in the JS code is altering the URL between the point where it was set and when I hit my breakpoint in my C#. Strange that I didn't catch this when I first saw it in the network trace in Chrome.

Comment: Assuming that actually works as a variable name, it should resolve to `SomeUrl/?_=ABC123`. (note the addition of the equals sign).  You might be better off trying to bind it as a first-class part of the URL path, as in  `SomeUrl/ABC123`

Comment: Yes, it works as a variable name. No, it doesn't bind. This is a third-party library and this is how it passes this variable (it's not my code I can easily change).